# How to retrieve user input and show user input card Javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Trying to filter user input so when user starts to type run function.

**What I want**

When the user starts to type, start looking for cards when the class `product-name` and display `block` results.

*ex:*

*user starts typing something...*
Piz

*display `block` card **Pizza***

**My Javascript**

```js
// search bar function
const search = () => {
    var input, filter, data, productName, i, txtValue;
    data = this.data;
    input = document.getElementById("user-input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    getInput = input.value;
    console.log("User input: " + getInput);
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.cards').forEach(function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            productName = data[i].querySelectorAll(".produce-name")[0];
            txtValue = productName.textContent || productName.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                data[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                data[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     });
};
```

**My HTML**

```html
<form class="form-inline flexSearchWrapper">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Busca algo..." aria-label="Search" id="user-input" onkeyup="search();">
</form>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? At the moment my `console.log()` output just gets the user input and what they are *currently* typing.Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**Card Info HTML**

```html
<div class="card cards">
  <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/185266/isolated/lists/815ded7afc1c54dfb5a60f81f68f928b-pizza-slice-icon.png" class="card-img-top p-3 product-image" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title product-name">Pizza</h5>
    <h5 class="text-muted fw-bold card-price product-price">S/ 12.50 PEN</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I put it in a `.forEach` loop in order to get the `.product-name` of each card.

Comment: It's hard to say. Could you add an HTML example of a single card? Also, what's the reason for looping within the `forEach`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks for responding so quick! I've updated the question with more info! Take a look.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier You are crazy good! That is insane I understand now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution isn't working because of a couple of issues:

1. You have a nested loop inside of `forEach`. `data` is a single card element. Looping through it will loop through it's properties, which is not what you need.
2. The product name is in the `.product-name` class, not the `.produce-name`. Also be sure to use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` if you need a single element.

Below I've written a different version of your code. Instead of looking up the title element of each card, add the data you need to the `.card` element itself. You can do this with [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In this case I've added `data-name` to each card, which is going to be the value which we can filter on.

Then when you input something in the search field, get the value of the field and loop over all the cards. If the `data-name` value contains anything that you've entered, then a class will be added or removed to show or hide the card. By using classes you can keep CSS in charge of the styles.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#search');
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

form.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const value = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  for (const card of cards) {
    const { name } = card.dataset;
    const shouldShow = name.includes(value);
    card.classList.toggle('hide', !shouldShow);
  }
});
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="search" class="form-inline flexSearchWrapper">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Busca algo..." aria-label="Search" id="user-input">
</form>

<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" data-name="pizza">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/185266/isolated/lists/815ded7afc1c54dfb5a60f81f68f928b-pizza-slice-icon.png" class="card-img-top p-3 product-image" alt="...">
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title product-name"><a href="#" class="test">Pizza</h5>
      <p class="text-muted fw-bold card-price product-price">S/ 12.50 PEN</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card" data-name="penne">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/185266/isolated/lists/815ded7afc1c54dfb5a60f81f68f928b-pizza-slice-icon.png" class="card-img-top p-3 product-image" alt="...">
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title product-name"><a href="#" class="test">Penne</h5>
      <p class="text-muted fw-bold card-price product-price">S/ 12.50 PEN</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also used the `cards` class differently as it doesn't make sense - at least for me - for a single card to have both `card` and `cards` as a class.

And be sure to use your headings `h1...h6` properly. It's not for styling but to explain to the browser how it should interpret the content.